# Android : Apply style to List and set a selected item shown in AlertDialog

Tags: android, list, styles, android-alertdialog, itemselector

I am showing a List in AlertDialog. I want to customize the list with some style (maybe custom). Also want an item to be selected in the list of Alert dialog. I have used very simple code :

```
                new AlertDialog.Builder(TrainsListActivity.this).setTitle(curTrainRoute.getName() + " to " + stationNames[which])
                .setItems(timeList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {         
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })

                .show();
```

I tried searching for the same, but couldn't find any resource for the same. Can you please help me out. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try to implemet a ListAdapter and set that to your AlertDialogBuilder. This allows much more control over what's layouted

Answer (score 0):

`setView()` method of alert dialog is useful, you can set `ListView` as custom view to your dialog.

for eg.

```
CustomDialogListAdapter adapter = new CustomDialogListAdapter();
        ListView list = new ListView(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                setTitle("item : " + arg2);
            }
        });

        final Builder dialogBuilder = new Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom List Dialog");
        dialogBuilder.setView(list);        
        dialogBuilder.create().show();
```

You can create custom adapter for list as follows

```
class CustomDialogListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        private String[] data = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names", "Fish Names" };
        private ArrayList<Boolean> checkboxStatus = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        public CustomDialogListAdapter() {
            int count = data.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                checkboxStatus.add(false);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.raw_dialog_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
                holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkboxListener);
                holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.chk.setTag("" + position);
            holder.chk.setChecked(checkboxStatus.get(position));
            holder.txt.setText(data[position]);

            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            CheckBox chk;
            TextView txt;
        }

        private OnCheckedChangeListener checkboxListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int position = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString());
                checkboxStatus.set(position, isChecked);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return data[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

    }
```

Raw file of list item (raw_dialog_item.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chkbox"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code using which you can able to set selector to listview in easy steps

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                                    alert.getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.listview_selector);
                                    alert.getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                    alert.getListView().invalidate();

                                alert.show();
```